# PHP Numbers increment inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach, numbers, increment

I want to increment the number values inside a foreach. This is the code that I am using.

```
foreach($numbers as $number) { 

$out .= '<li>'.$number.'</li>';

}

echo $out;
```

This should generate something like this

```
1
4
2300
9
0
```

Now I want to increment all this numbers to result.

```
2314
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and also, what is the logic / rules behind the increment?

Comment: What makes 4 come after 1 and 2300 after 4? Without that algo no one can produce the output only you know

Comment: A script that calculate the size_download of css, js, images files and after that generate the total size of page.

Comment: Reading the few data example you gave, I think you want to sum those numbers, not increment them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$total=0;
foreach($numbers as $number) { 
 $total =  $total+(int)$number;
 $out .= '<li>'.$number.'</li>';
 echo $out;
}
echo "Total ".$total ."<br/>"
```